# Pegar elemento por id em outra página por javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho duas páginas: A e B. Em B eu faço uma pesquisa e monto uma table(HTML) e defino um ID para ela. Em A tenho a chamada da table e dependendo da situação, eu exibo ou não a table. Isso já funcionava com o ebagrid o qual eu estou substituindo com html puro. Como eu faço para aplicar um display none nele, buscando pelo ID? Acontece que a table é criada na Página B e por ajax eu descarrego na página A? Tenho algo assim:

```
document.getElementById('grid_dentes_d').style.display = '';
```

Como o ID é declarado na página B, ele sempre vem null e dá pau. Pensei em criar as colunas da table(thead) na página A, e descarregar apenas o conteúdo dela por ajax(tbody) na página A, isso é bom, não dá pau ou é pura gambi? Nunca fiz isso.

Página B:

```
Case "grid_dentes_d"    'GRID DENTES PERMANENTES

        redim Vet_PL(2,4)

        Vet_PL(1, 1) = "IN"
        Vet_PL(1, 2) = "adVarChar"
        Vet_PL(1, 3) = "p_item_medico"
        Vet_PL(1, 4) = request("item_medico")

        Vet_PL(2, 1) = "IN"
        Vet_PL(2, 2) = "adVarChar"
        Vet_PL(2, 3) = "p_ind_tipo"
        Vet_PL(2, 4) = "D"

        set rsPesquisa = rsCursorOracle(CStr(Session("ace_usuario")), _
                                     CStr(Session("ace_senha")), _
                                     CStr(Session("ace_ip")), _
                                     cstr(Session("ace_sistema")), _
                                     CStr(Session("ace_modulo")), _
                                     "ODO_RCS_PROCEDIMENTO.get_lista_dentes", _
                                     Vet_PL, _
                                     false )

         sRetornoDenteD = "<table border='1' id='grid_dentes_d'>"
         sRetornoDenteD = "<thead>"
         sRetornoDenteD = sRetornoDenteD & "<tr>"
         sRetornoDenteD = sRetornoDenteD & "<th style='border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px class='label_right' nowrap><center>Habilitado</center></th>"
         sRetornoDenteD = sRetornoDenteD & "<th style='border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px class='label_right' nowrap><center>Código</center></th>"
         sRetornoDenteD = sRetornoDenteD & "<th style='border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px class='label_right' nowrap><center>Nome</center></th>"
         sRetornoDenteD = sRetornoDenteD & "</tr>"
         sRetornoDenteD = sRetornoDenteD & "</thead>"

         sRetornoDenteD = sRetornoDenteD & "<tbody>"


        Do While Not rsPesquisa.eof

            sRetornoDenteD = sRetornoDenteD & "<tr>"
            sRetornoDenteD = sRetornoDenteD & "<td style='border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px' class='label_right'><center>"&rsPesquisa("IND_MARCADO")&"</center></td>" 
            sRetornoDenteD = sRetornoDenteD & "<td style='border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px' class='label_right'><center>"&rsPesquisa("COD_DENTE")&"</center></td>" 
            sRetornoDenteD = sRetornoDenteD & "<td style='border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px' class='label_right' align='center'>"&rsPesquisa("NOM_DENTE")&"</td>" 
            sRetornoDenteD = sRetornoDenteD & "</tr>"

            rsPesquisa.movenext
        loop

        sRetornoDenteD = sRetornoDenteD & "</tbody>"
        sRetornoDenteD = sRetornoDenteD & "</table>"
        Response.write sRetornoDenteD

        set oPesquisa = nothing
```

Página A

```
function CarregaTabelaDenteD() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'odo_hes0002d_crossbrowser.asp?item_medico=<%=item_medico%>&tipo_grid=grid_dentes_dec',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#retornoDentesD').html(data);
            },
            error: function (error) {
            }
        })
    }
```

Onde dá o erro(A):

```
function habilita_campos_odonto() {
        var indTipoOdonto = document.form01.ind_tipo_odonto.value;
        document.getElementById('dente_label').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('dente_campos').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('face_label').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('face_campos').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('tipo_dente_label').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('tipo_dente_campos').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('grid_regiao').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('regioes').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('field_regiao').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('grid_dentes_d').style.display = 'none';//**AQUI DÁ O ERRO**
        document.getElementById('grid_dentes_p').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('field_dt_permanentes').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('field_dt_deciduos').style.display = 'none';

        document.getElementById('field_dentes_p').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('field_dentes_d').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('tipo_dente_campos_d').style.display = 'none';


        if (document.form01.ind_tipo_odonto.value == 1)  //POR DENTE
        {

            limpaGridDente("grid_dentes_d");
            limpaGridDente("grid_dentes_p");

            document.getElementById('dente_label').style.display = '';
            document.getElementById('dente_campos').style.display = '';
            document.getElementById('tipo_dente_label').style.display = '';
            document.getElementById('tipo_dente_campos').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('grid_regiao').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('regioes').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('field_regiao').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('qtd_face_dente_de').value = '';
            document.getElementById('qtd_face_dente_ate').value = '';
            document.getElementById('grid_dentes_p').style.display = '';
            document.getElementById('grid_dentes_d').style.display = '';
            document.getElementById('field_dentes_p').style.display = '';
            document.getElementById('field_dentes_d').style.display = '';
            document.getElementById('tipo_dente_campos_d').style.display = '';
        } else {
            if (document.form01.ind_tipo_odonto.value == 2) //POR REGIÃO
            {
                document.getElementById('dente_label').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('dente_campos').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('face_label').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('face_campos').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('tipo_dente_label').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('tipo_dente_campos').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('grid_regiao').style.display = '';
                document.getElementById('regioes').style.display = '';
                document.getElementById('field_regiao').style.display = '';
             //   document.getElementById('qtd_dente_de').value = '';
             //   document.getElementById('qtd_dente_ate').value = '';
                document.getElementById('qtd_face_dente_de').value = '';
                document.getElementById('qtd_face_dente_ate').value = '';

                document.getElementsByName('ind_tipo_dente_f')[0].checked = true;
            }
            else {
                if (document.form01.ind_tipo_odonto.value == 3) //POR DENTE OU REGIÃO
                {
                    //document.getElementById('dente_label').style.display = '';
                    //document.getElementById('dente_campos').style.display = '';
                    document.getElementById('tipo_dente_label').style.display = '';
                    document.getElementById('tipo_dente_campos').style.display = 'none';
                    document.getElementById('grid_regiao').style.display = '';
                    document.getElementById('regioes').style.display = '';
                    document.getElementById('field_regiao').style.display = '';
                    document.getElementById('qtd_face_dente_de').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('qtd_face_dente_ate').value = '';
                    document.getElementById('grid_dentes_p').style.display = '';
                    document.getElementById('grid_dentes_d').style.display = '';
                    document.getElementById('field_dentes_p').style.display = '';
                    document.getElementById('field_dentes_d').style.display = '';
                    document.getElementById('tipo_dente_campos_d').style.display = '';
                } else {
                    if (document.form01.ind_tipo_odonto.value == 4) //POR DENTE E FACE
                    {

                        limpaGridFace("grid_dentes_dec");  //se houver mudança no da combo, o sistemna limpa a grid.
                        limpaGridFace("grid_dentes_perm");

                        document.getElementById('dente_label').style.display = '';
                        document.getElementById('dente_campos').style.display = '';
                        document.getElementById('face_label').style.display = '';
                        document.getElementById('face_campos').style.display = '';
                        document.getElementById('tipo_dente_label').style.display = '';
                        document.getElementById('tipo_dente_campos').style.display = '';
                        document.getElementById('grid_regiao').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('regioes').style.display = 'none';
                        document.getElementById('field_regiao').style.display = 'none';
                    }
                }z
            }
        }

        if (((indTipoOdonto == 1) || (indTipoOdonto == 2) || (indTipoOdonto == 3) || (indTipoOdonto == 4)) && (document.getElementById('tipo_dente_campos').style.display == '')) {
            ExibeFieldsetDente();

        } else {
            if (document.form01.ind_tipo_odonto.value != "" && document.form01.ind_tipo_odonto.value!=2) {
                ExibeFieldsetDenteD();
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: é importante saber que pagina realiza a chamada, por exemplo, o usuario entra na pagina A, realiza uma a

Comment: Cara ficou meio confuso, poderia postar o seu código para que possamos lhe ajudar.

Comment: @TobyMosque, então. A página B ela é apenas uma página auxiliar, o usuário não tem acesso a ela, somente pelas chamadas em A e nada mais.

Comment: @RomarioPires, meu código é apenas a montagem de uma table e uma função jquery/ajax para popular em uma div o conteúdo da table. A pergunta é como eu pego o ID da table que está na página B em A.

Comment: @pnet não seria viável carregar a página B por trás ? com isso você conseguiria obter seu ID

Comment: @ThiagoFriedman, a B é apenas uma página auxiliar. Não possui nem cabeçalho, nem includes nem nada. Só tem umas funções em ASP, um recordset e agora minha table.

Comment: Olhando o seu Html do arquivo B, não vejo nenhum id, você não pode procurar por algo que não existe.

Comment: @TobyMosque, esse aqui: sRetornoDenteD = "<table border='1' id='grid_dentes_d'>"

Comment: Você está chamando a função de habilitar campos antes ou depois da função AJAX.

Comment: Está vindo após, ambas estão sendo chamada numa função chamada init(). Primeiro vem a do ajax e depois a habilita.

Comment: podes sempre usar o campo serialize do js

Comment: @user2964140, como eu faço isso? Coloquei a resposta, consegui montar a tabela, mas continua com o problema de ID. Acho melhor até remover a resposta que coloquei.

Comment: so tens de https://api.jquery.com/serialize/ ai tens depois só tens de envia o valor da varivel no campo data apos o post...e chamas em php o valor da variável que queres

Answer (score 1):

vamos supor as seguintes paginas:

**Pagina A**

```
<input id="toggleMsg" type="button" value="Toggle Mensagem em Pagina B" />
```

**Pagina B**

```
<style>
  .invisivel {
    display: none;
  }
</style>
<div id="mensagem">
  Hello Wolrd!
</div>
```

Então temos o seguinte cenário.

1. No caso a `Pagina A` irá abrir um popup com a `pagina B`.
2. A `Pagina A` poderá altenar a class `invisível` da `div#mensagem` da `pagina B`

Então ao abrir o pop-up, você pode armazenar a janela aberta em uma variável. Desta forma você poderá acessar os elementos desta janela apartir da variável.

```js
//criando a URL para a pagina B.
var toggleMsg = document.getElementById("toggleMsg");
var paginaB = document.getElementById("paginaB");
var blobB = new Blob([paginaB.innerHTML], { type: paginaB.type });
var urlB = URL.createObjectURL(blobB);

//abriando o pop-up com a pagina B e acessando o seu elemento.
var windowB = window.open(urlB);
toggleMsg.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
  var mensagem = windowB.document.getElementById("mensagem");
  mensagem.classList.toggle("invisivel");
});
```

```html
<input id="toggleMsg" type="button" value="Toggle Mensagem em Pagina B" />

<!-- Template para criar a Pagina B -->
<script id="paginaB" type="text/html">
  <style>
    .invisivel {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>
  <div id="mensagem">
    Hello Wolrd!
  </div>
</script>
```

Como não é possível abrir um Popup a partir de um Snippet aqui no Stackoverflow, então o exemplo acima não vai funcionar. Em todo caso você pode olhar o mesmo funcionando no seguinte [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cwe0un3p/).

Comment: O popup da página B é que não tenho como abrir. Vou editar e postar a minha table e a minha função ajax e as chamadas

Comment: a sua pergunta era sobre pegar um elemento por id em outra janela, já que a pergunta que fez não reflete o problema, o ideal é fazer uma nova pergunta.

Comment: Mas pelo o que está me dizendo, B não é uma página, mas um fragmento de HTML que você incluiu na página A. Não há problema nenhum em fazer isto, inclusive este é a base do SPA (single page application). Mas apesar de serem dois arquivos distintos no servidor, você tem apenas uma página/documento.

Comment: Estou vendo que não é possível pegar o ID de um elemento em uma página a partir de outra, certo?

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi assim. Montei o cabeçalho da table no próprio ajax(o id ficou na mesma página) e apenas adicionei o body da table por ajax, vindo da outra página. Isso resolveu:

```
function CarregaTabelaDenteD() {

        var str = '';

        $.ajax({
            url: 'odo_hes0002d_crossbrowser.asp?item_medico=<%=item_medico%>&tipo_grid=grid_dentes_dec',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {

                str = str + '<table border="1" id="grid_dentes_d">';
                str = str + '<thead>';
                str = str + '<tr>';
                str = str + '<th style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px" class="label_right" nowrap><center>Habilitado</center></th>';
                str = str + '<th style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px" class="label_right" nowrap><center>Código</center></th>';
                str = str + ' <th style="border-bottom:0px;border-left:0px" class="label_right" nowrap><center>Nome</center></th>';
                str = str + '</tr>';
                str = str + '</thead>';

                str = str + '<tbody>';

                str = str + data;//Aqui o que vem do oracle da outra página

                $('#retornoDentesD').html(str);
            },
            error: function (error) {
            }
        })
        str = '';
    }
```